# Michell FPL 2.3.5 (observable types)

Tags: logic, solution-verification, proof-theory, type-theory, lambda-calculus

(a) Show that the relation of observational equivalence remains the same when changing the observable types of pcf from *nat, bool* to *nat*. (b) Further show that changing from *nat,bool* to *nat, bool, product*, where product is the product of two observable types, does not change the relation of observational equivalence.

Terminology: let $=_n, =_p$ represent the equivalence relation whose observable types are *nat*, and *nat, bool, prod* resp. let = be the standard equivlanece, ie the one whose observables include nat and bool. The values of pcf are the boolean and natural constants, as well as lambda abstractions.

(a): Given m $=_n$ n. If c[] is such that c[m], c[n] are closed of type nat, we are done by hypothesis. So let c[] be such that c[m], c[n] are closed of type bool. WTS that eval(c[m]) $\simeq$ eval(c[n]). Let d[] be the context formed by "if c[] then 1 else 0". We have that d[m], d[n] are closed of type nat, by hypothesis eval(d[m]) $\simeq$ eval(d[n]). Suppose that d[m] has a normal form, henceforth nf. **since closed nf of observable type are values, d[m] must be either 0 or 1. by inversion, c[m] must thus be true or false, hence c[m] has a normal form.** Further c[m], c[n] must have the same nf, else d[m], d[n] do not. On the other hand, if d[m] does not have a nf, then c[m] cannot either. for if c[m] has a nf such as true or false, d[m] clearly does by apply reduction rule for conditional. Hence proved.

(b): very similar, but we construct d[] by induction on the depth of the product types. for example, suppose c[m], c[n] are of type (nat x bool) x nat. We can code $\land$ in pcf, so we allow d[] = if $p_1(p_1(c[]))= 0 \land p_1(p_2(c[]) \land p_2(c[])$ then 0 else 1. Then d[m], d[n] have type nat, and we can proceed as in part (a).

Q: doe this seem right? crucially for part a, do we have closed nf of observable type are values? I think so, likely via a progress theorem. Alternatively, is there another way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, we have something stronger: closed nf of observable type are either numerals or boolean constants.

Pf: We can induct on the typing derivation. The base cases for the numbers and booleans are clearly true. Suppose we have $H \vdash eq? (x) (y) : bool$, and $eq (x) (y)$ is a closed nf of type bool. In particular, no reduction rule can apply to x or y, by inversion and then inductive hypothesis this means that x, y are numerals. But then we have that $eq (x)(y)$ steps to true or false, ie is not in nf. Here is another case: Suppose $H \vdash M(N): t$ is closed of ground type. By inversion, M is of function type, ie a lambda term, and hence beta-reduction applies so that M(N) is not in nf. On the other hand, our term cannot be a fix term since fix terms can always be reduced. The other cases are similar.